# What is the most standards compliant way to send a fax from an application?

Tags: language-agnostic, api, voip, telephony, fax

From what I understand fax over VoIP is very unreliable due to the real-time requirements of the fax protocol. Simply using VoIP to send fax message to POTS-connected fax machines is hence not possible.

Besides from proprietary fax API:s (such as sending fax messages via a company specific SOAP API), what standards based protocols are there for sending fax messages programmatically over IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [fax-over-IP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T.38).

If you don't control the QoS (e.g. delays) of the network, then a more reliable way is to use a store-and-forward mechanism (e.g. email) to route the image though the (non-real-time) cloud, to a fax server on the other side, which then sends the fax over a real-time Plain Old Telephone line.

Answer (score 0):

If  you  are  looking for  Fax  over  SIP  then  mostly  sip  providers  adopt  one  on these two  methods mentioed  below

1. Fax  transmission using  T.38 protocol
2. G.711  pass through

T.38  is  more  reliable therefore   preferred  for fax communication and  when  there  is  non availability  or  compatibility  issues  then  G.711 fax pass through is option  for fax transmission

Following  is  an open source  project based on freeswitch  that  deploy both stratgies

http://www.ictfax.org